# Troubleshoot my addInOrder method that won't implement my compareTo method correctly

Tags: java

I have to use this addInOrder method to add people to my LinkedList but in alphabetical order by lastName then firstName. Once I add the person into the list I have to return true or false depending on if it added it or not. I created a compareTo method that returns 0 if two entries have the same first name and same last name. It would return -1 if the lastName comes alphabetically before the object it's being compared to (if the lastName is the same then it resorts to checking the firstName). Finally, it would return 1 if the name is alphabetically after the object it is being compared to. I've tested the compareTo method multiple times and can confirm it works. This is the code for it:

```
public int compareTo(PhoneDirectoryEntry other) {

        if (this.firstName.equals(other.firstName) && this.lastName.equals(other.lastName)) {
            return 0;
        } else if (this.lastName.compareTo(other.lastName) < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (this.lastName.compareTo(other.lastName) > 0) {
            return 1;  
        } else if (this.firstName.compareTo(other.firstName) < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else
            return 1;
        }
    }
```

My problem relies in my addInOrder method.

```
public boolean addInOrder(String firstName, String lastName, String phoneNumber) {
        //to be completed by you
        if (list.isEmpty()) {
                PhoneDirectoryEntry person = new PhoneDirectoryEntry(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);
                list.add(person);
                return true;
        } for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
            if (list.get(i).getLastName().compareTo(lastName) == -1) {
                PhoneDirectoryEntry person = new PhoneDirectoryEntry(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);
                list.add(i, person);
                return true;
            } else if (list.get(i).getLastName().compareTo(lastName) == 1) {
                PhoneDirectoryEntry person = new PhoneDirectoryEntry(firstName, lastName, phoneNumber);
                list.add(i++, person);
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

My first if statement works perfectly and will always manage to add a person to the empty list. The for loop also runs. The problem is within the if statement. I've tried all variations of the if statement like:

`list.get(i).getLastName().compareTo(lastName) == -1 || list.get(i).getFirstName().compareTo(firstName) == 1`

And none of them has worked. So I'm just stuck with this line. If anyone can see my problem or needs more information let me know. Thanks.

Comment: `compareTo` won't return just `-1`, `0` or `1`, it can return a range of negative and positive values.  You code isn't using your `compareTo` method, it's using `String`s, `list.get(i).getLastName()`.  Assuming `list` contains `PhoneDirectoryEntry`, you might consider using `list.get(i).compareTo(person)` instead, but you'd need to create the `PhoneDirectoryEntry` object first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your compareTo method takes PhoneDirectoryEntry class, so it will compare two PhoneDirectoryEntry object. What you are doing in the for loop is to get the last name in your PhoneDirectoryEntry class, and call string's compareTo method. String's compareTo method is the one implemented by java, not your compareTo method.